# Modify INCS in makefile depending on target?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile where I want to make a new target. Now basically the version of a third party library being used for the new target would be an upgraded one. We want to create a new target for the application which specifically uses the upgraded version. So as of now there are many different application complied into a single binary ( probably not a good thing , was done historically ) uses old version of that third party library. We do not want to make multiple GNUmakefile, so we were thinking of adding and building a new target. But we have something like INCS which tells which all folder to be included while compiling the c++ code. Now as of now we have old version of third party library included in it. Is there a way conditional statement in  INCS to include the latest third party folder if my target is different ?

```
INCS += \
        -I${DEP_PATH}/3rdPartyLib-1.0/include \
        -I${DEP_PATH}/3rdPartyLib-2.0/include \
        -I${DEP_PATH}/Util/include \

all: Application1${EXEEXT}
     ${EXETOOL} ${CCC} ${CCFLAGS} -o $@ $? $(LIBS)

app2: Application2${EXEEXT}
      ${EXETOOL} ${CCC} ${CCFLAGS} -o $@ $? $(LIBS)
```

When we do make app2 use 3rdPartyLib-2.0 while for make all use 3rdPartyLib-1.0 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can use [target-specific variable assignments](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific), which will be set for the target and propagate down to all dependencies. Consider the following `Makefile`:

```
DEP_PATH := dep

INCS += \
        -I$(DEP_PATH)/Util/include

all: INCS += -I$(DEP_PATH)/3rdPartyLib-1.0/include
all: Application1$(EXEEXT)

app2: INCS += -I$(DEP_PATH)/3rdPartyLib-2.0/include
app2: Application2$(EXEEXT)

all app2:
        echo Making $@ with INCS = $(INCS)

Application1$(EXEEXT) Application2$(EXEEXT):
        echo Making $@ with INCS = $(INCS)
```

Output:

```
$ make -s all app2
Making Application1 with INCS = -Idep/Util/include -Idep/3rdPartyLib-1.0/include
Making all with INCS = -Idep/Util/include -Idep/3rdPartyLib-1.0/include
Making Application2 with INCS = -Idep/Util/include -Idep/3rdPartyLib-2.0/include
Making app2 with INCS = -Idep/Util/include -Idep/3rdPartyLib-2.0/include
```

Note how different includes were used for `all` and `app2` and how it was propagated down to `...$(EXEEXT)` targets.

Comment: will try this and if works fine will accept this as an answer.